# I was wondering what does While(cin) test?

Tags: c++

I'm reading a book, *"Software - Principles and Practice using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup*, and this code was presented:

```
Token get_token();
vector<Token>tok;

int main()
{
    while(cin)
    {
        Token t = get_token();
        tok.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

what does the while check?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that it is explained in detail in the book "Software - Principles and Practice using C++", by Bjarne Stroustrup. If you have it handy, check it out.

Comment: This code seems wrong. `get_token` can fail reading the input even if `while (cin)` tested true. Was Stroustrup using this code to demonstrate a common mistake? The correct way to write an input loop is `while (cin >> ...) { ...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while` casts its condition expression result into `bool`. According to that, in case of iostreams it invokes [std::ios::operator bool](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/):

> Returns whether an error flag is set (either `failbit` or `badbit`).
>
> Notice that this function does not return the same as member `good`, but the opposite of member `fail`.

Model example shows which bits are set and when:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void foo(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) {

    std::string str;
    out << "goodbit | eofbit | failbit | badbit | string" << std::endl;

    while(true) {
        in >> str;

        auto s = in.rdstate();

        out
                << std::setw(7) << bool(s & std::ios::goodbit) << " | "
                << std::setw(6) << bool(s & std::ios::eofbit)  << " | "
                << std::setw(7) << bool(s & std::ios::failbit) << " | "
                << std::setw(6) << bool(s & std::ios::badbit)  << " | ";

        if(in) {
                out << str << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            out << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

}

int main(void) {

    foo(std::cin, std::cout);

    return 0;
}
```

`$ echo "a ab" | ./untitled` (input is piped) prints

```
goodbit | eofbit | failbit | badbit | string
      0 |      0 |       0 |      0 | a
      0 |      0 |       0 |      0 | ab
      0 |      1 |       1 |      0 |
```

Comment: can you elaborate on it a little more in detail? I read on it and what i am reading is that the cin checks whether the input stream is in good state correct? my question is how would it be if there is nothing to input to at that time?

Comment: i think i get what you are saying. What i am understanding is that cin is being evaluated as being good, failbit, or badbit? If the too error flags are not set the condition of cin is good? Another question can the input stream be checked prior to any request for input?

Comment: @KevinWiggins _Notice that this function does **not** return the same as member `good`, but **the opposite** of member `fail`_. Yes, it can be checked by reading (or writing for output streams) and checking state for errors. You can only check state which **was** set by previous operations.